# how to direct desktop website away from mobile website on desktop with php

Tags: php, redirect, mobile, web, desktop

If a desktop user open mobile website, the code would redirect the user to desktop website.

```
<?php
// Apple iOS devices
    $iPhone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone');
    $iPod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod');
    $iPad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad');

// Android devices
    $Android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android');

// All mobile devices
    $Mobile = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Mobile');

// BlackBerry devices
    $BlackBerry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'BlackBerry');

// Nokia SymbianOS devices
    $Symbian = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Symbian');

// HTC devices
    $HTC = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'HTC_');  

// Windows Phone devices
    $WP7 = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'WP7');
    $WP8 = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'WP8');

// Browser's OS devices
    $webOS = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'webOS');

// Mobile browser (Opera, Firefox)
    $Opera_M = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Opera M');
    $Fennec = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Fennec/');

if ($iPhone || $iPod || $iPad || $Android || $Mobile || $BlackBerry || $Symbian || $HTC || $WP7 || $WP8 || $webOS || $Opera_M || $Fennec == true) 
{ 
header('Location: http://m.website.com/');
//OR
echo "<script>window.location='http://m.website.com'</script>";
}
?>
```

Can I add if and else to redirect user to desktop website such as

```
else {header('Location: http://website.com/');
//OR
echo "<script>window.location='http://website.com'</script>";
}
```

The else part seems not work because the browser on desktop and mobile display too many redirect error.
Thanks

Comment: Syntax is `else {header('Location: http://website.com/');}` - Plus, it should work. What "errors" are you getting?

Comment: You can't use header and echo at the same time; most likely why you're getting errors. Use one or the other.

Comment: After I add else {header('Location: http://website.com/');} ,       I got This webpage has a redirect loop error on Chrome, The page isn't redirecting properly

and on Firefox, Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies. error on Firefox

Comment: Check to see if the site/page you want it redirected to, doesn't contain the opposite, or something in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: After I modified the code to                                                 { 
header('Location: http://m.website.com/');
} else {header('Location: http://website.com/');}
?>  I still get the same error

Comment: My .htacess contains the code: DirectoryIndex index2.php index.php 
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
I don't see anything that would conflict with my code

Comment: When I don't include any else syntax, the code would work on redirect desktop to mobile website on mobile. Chrome and Firefox don't show any error. I want to find a way to redirect mobile to desktop website on desktop.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for your request for clarification.

Comment: You're welcome Alessandro; wish I could have been of more help, but was unable to replicate and find the problem, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I solved the problem. The php code in index website is conflict with php code (like above) in other php file. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's great, glad to hear it. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming :

```
function isMobile() {
    /* return true if is on tablet / phone */
}
```

On mobile version :

```
if (!isMobile()) {
    header('Location: website.com');
    exit;
}
```

On desktop version :

```
if (isMobile()) {
    header('Location: m.website.com');
    exit;
}
```